# Unable to change any config in Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: unity, updates, compiz, launcher, configuration

I'm running Ubuntu 14.10 on a custom PC and something around 1 hour ago my PC just froze. The mouse and keyboard were unresponsive and I was unable to change to another tty, so I pressed the reset button on my pc and when It turned on, my wallpaper have reset to the original as well as all my compiz and unity configs. At first I thought the configuration had reset but when I tried to adjust it I failed.

When I unlock an item from the launcher it just reappear a few seconds later. When I try to maximize the launcher it just maximizes for a fraction of a second and goes to the normal size. When I lock a new icon to the launcher, it disappears a few seconds later. In the unity tweak tool, system settings or compiz config if I change an option it goes back to the previous state instantly, like if I check a checkbox it automatically unchecks and the same for all the options (switches, drop down menus, texts fields, etc...)

The only lead I have is that I install some updates (ubuntu base) a few hours before my computer crashing. I don't know if something is broken in the new update or what is happening.

Somebody has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I would create a new user, and see if they have the same problem.   Just a guess here I think it may be a config issue.

Since it does not re-appear with a new user it's a config file somewhere.   I would google resetting (insertyourguihere) to defaults and see what that does.  If you had a highly customized desktop or something like that bear in mind you will lose your desktop tweaks and it will be back to where you started to build from.  Guessing one of the unity/gnome kidz may answer that better.....

Comment: Just created a new user. It works fine. How do I fix my user?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I hate configuring the desktop, it's just the place where you click on the app shou really want to use. I have normal unity with some little compiz tweaks so it should be no problem.

Comment: No worries.  Cheers.